# Calculate expanding standard deviation on a group

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to calculate the expanding standard deviation of a a group. I've tried the following:

```
df['RunStdDev']  =  df.groupby(['LEFT PORT DATE TIME'])['SPEED'].apply.pd.expanding_std()
```

I get error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'expanding_std'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are your parentheses correct?  This ` df.groupby(['LEFT PORT DATE TIME'])['SPEED'].apply.pd.expanding_std()` should be ` df.groupby(['LEFT PORT DATE TIME']['SPEED']).apply.pd.expanding_std() ` ?

Comment: Good point, but it's not the parentheses. If I changes to your suggestion I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running latest pandas version?

```
df['RunStdDev']  =  df.groupby(['LEFT PORT DATE TIME'])['SPEED'].expanding().std()
```

[pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Expanding.std.html)

> ```
> Expanding.std(self, ddof=1, *args, **kwargs)
> ```

Comment: Yes, I've checked now... I'm on `(0.25.2)`

Answer (score 0):

It should be working

```
df['RunStdDev']  =  df.groupby['LEFT PORT DATE TIME']['SPEED'].apply.expanding_std()
```

You do not have to use `.pd` after `apply` function as `df` is an actuall `pandas` object with its methods imported.

Comment: I get now this error `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable'`

Comment: Change ```[...]``` to ```(...)``` in ```df.groupby('LEFT PORT DATE TIME')```